# Is it possible to impose a minimum niceness on a specific user?

Tags: limit

Is it possible to limit a specific user's processes to always run with a niceness of at least 15, say?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set per-user or per-group nice values using `pam_limits` and the `/etc/security/limits.conf` file.

e.g.

```
username    hard    priority    15
```

This only affects PAM services which are configured to **use** the `pam_limits` module.  Depending on your distribution, this is probably already enabled for services like `login`, `cron`, `atd`, `sshd`, and others.  Or you may have to enable it by adding a line like the following to, e.g., `/etc/pam.d/login`:

```
session    required   pam_limits.so
```

See `man pam_limits` and the comments in `/etc/security/limits.conf` for details.
If you have the PAM doc package installed, there may be additional documentation at `/usr/share/doc/libpam-doc/html/sag-pam_limits.html`